# Let $ A={z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|>1 }$ and $ B={z \in \mathbb{C}: z \neq 0}$ then which of the following is true.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $ A=\lbrace z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|>1 \rbrace$ and $ B=\lbrace z \in \mathbb{C}: z \neq 0\rbrace $ then which of the following is true.
The options are
a. There exists a continuous onto function from A to B

b. There exists a continuous one one function from B to A

c. There exists a non constant analytic function from A to B

d. There exists a non constant analytic function from B to A

I Can prove that C is true by taking just an inclusion map. Also i can prove that d is not true. As if it is true then say there is some non constant analytic function f from B to A. then clearly the function has either pole or essential singularity at 0 but then by picards theorem(in first case) and by casorati Weirstrass theorem(in second case) we get a contradiction to function being non constant. So c option is false.

Now topologicaly both the sets A and B are connected, non compact, open etc. so have same properties.So trying a few example it seems that 1 is true by considering $f(z)=e^z$. And i think option B is true as we can have f to be some specific branch of logarithm. or function can also be defined in such a way that it shifts all the points continuously 1 unit distance radially outward i.e. $f(z)=(r+1)e^{i \theta}$ where $z=re^{i\theta}$.Is this argument right?

Comment: CSIR NET 2016 june question. I think it is duplicate/somewhat related-http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833661/one-one-continuous-function-from-z-in-mathbbcz1-to-z-in-mathbbc?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @vidyarthi that question is somewhat related to first 2 options but i need reverse way function.

Answer (score 0):

For options a) and b), we may use the fact that the punctured plane is homeomorphic to the compliment of closed unit disc

Comment: ok. But is my argument right?

Comment: @Prajakta yes, since the question asks only for existence, therefore examples may suffice. But, the general property in the background is, I think, homeomorphism.

Comment: ok. right. thanks. can you share a link of proof of homeomorphism?

Comment: @Prajakta This is  somewhat related --http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1920002/construct-a-homeomorphism-between-the-punctured-plane-and-the-annulus

Answer (score -2):

1.$f(z)=$ \begin{cases}|z| &\text{if} |z|>1\\\dfrac{1}{|z|} &\text{if}|z|\le 1\end{cases}

2..$f(z)=$ \begin{cases}e^z &\text{if} |z|>1\\\dfrac{1}{e^z} &\text{if}|z|\le 1\end{cases}

3.You are correct

4. $(d)$ ;

If $f:B\to A$ then $|f(z)|>1\forall z$.

Hence define $g(z)=\dfrac{1}{f(z)}$ which is entire .Also $|g(z)|<1$ Hence $g$ is bounded entire function and so constant and hence so is $f$

Comment: I am not getting how it answers b

Comment: Sorry it will be d

Comment: ya then its fine.

Comment: $f$ is not onto